# How to specify the quote to use for strings in a python list for mysql?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

My list is as follows:

```
['1.0.176.20:14386', '1.0.179.115:20208', '1.0.218.241:14699', '1.0.242.3:27376', '1.1.218.165:24513']
```

from:

```
sessions = [session[0].replace("'", '"') for session in sessions]
```

But in mysql:

```
cur.execute("""
        SELECT *
        FROM logs
        WHERE logs.session IN %s
        """, (
            sessions,
        ))
```

it returns nothing because of query being:

```
SELECT *
        FROM logs
        WHERE logs.session IN ("'1.0.176.20:14386'", "'1.0.179.115:20208'")
```

How do I fix this in mysql/list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you format that string what you will get is

```
... WHERE logs.session IN ['1.0.176.20:14386', '1.0.179.115:20208', (...)]
```

because that is the string representation of a list (`[...]`).

You need to do something like this:

```
sessions_in = ",".join(map(lambda x: "'{0}'".format(x), sessions))
cur.execute("""
    SELECT *
    FROM logs
    WHERE logs.session IN ( {0} )
    """.format(sessions_in))
```

It will create a string by joining all the list items with a `,` between them. As this would only create a single string with all the elements inside it (`"1,2,3,(...)"`), you need to transform each string into a quoted string before joining them. That's what that `map` will do, giving you:

```
"'1.0.176.20:14386','1.0.179.115:20208','1.0.218.241:14699','1.0.242.3:27376','1.1.218.165:24513'"
```

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate a bit more?